# How to prepare USB HDD from FreeBSD CD ISO image?

Tags: freebsd

I have downloaded the FreeBSD 10 x86 CD ISO image file.

I have a Dell Optiplex Pentium 4 2.66Ghz PC which supports booting from USB.

I have a 500 GB external USB hard drive.

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro on a separate laptop.

Question: How to copy the ISO image to the external hard drive so that I can use it to install FreeBSD on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

dd in Linux, or [unetbootin on various. platforms](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), also this is fairly well documented in the [FreeBSD Documentation.](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-pre.html)